# LibGDX bitmap font not getting rendered

Tags: fonts, libgdx

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(123, 5, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);

    batch.begin();
    black.draw(batch, "some string", Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 + 100);
    stage.draw();
    //white.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    batch.end();
}
```

this is the show method

```
@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("data/button.pack");
    skin = new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(atlas);
    white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/whitefont.fnt"), false);
    black = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font_1.fnt"), false);
}
```

when using the font on a button it gets rendered but when I simply want to draw it on the screen next to the button it wont. Is it because of the stage?!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the text displayed by using a Label and adding it to the stage

```
    LabelStyle ls = new LabelStyle(black, Color.WHITE);
    label = new Label("pishateee", ls);
    label.setX(0);
    label.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 + 100);
    label.setWidth(width);
    label.setAlignment(Align.center);

    stage.addActor(label);
```

all the work gets done by stage.draw() in the render method.